# BubbleSort na key 3 de uma tupla?

Tags: python-3.x

Eu possuo uma tupla com os seguintes valores:

```py
('beringela', 10, 1.99)
('arroz', 5, 4.99)
('peixe', 2, 9.99)
('abacaxi', 100, 3.99)
```

Preciso ordená-la pela terceira coluna, porém **não posso usar metodos de organização BuiltIn do Python3**, ou seja, preciso fazer o meu próprio `produtos.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])` na mão.

Para ordenar pelo primeiro e segundo campo eu usei o BubbleSort, mas não estou conseguindo usar para o terceiro campo. Segue o código que utilizei para os dois primeiros campos:

```py
def ordenaCampoUm(produtos):
    tam = len(produtos)
    for i in range(tam):
        troca = False
        for j in range(1, tam-i):
            if produtos[j] < produtos[j-1]:
                produtos[j], produtos[j - 1] = produtos[j-1], produtos[j]
                troca = True
        if not troca:
            break

    print("----- Listagem dos Produtos Ordenados Pelo Campo: 1 -----")
    for linha in produtos:
        print(tuple(linha))
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print()

def ordenaCampoDois(produtos):
    tam = len(produtos)
    for i in range(tam):
        for j in range(0, tam-i-1):
            if produtos[j][1] > produtos[j+1][1]:
                temp = produtos[j]
                produtos[j] = produtos[j+1]
                produtos[j+1] = temp

    print("----- Listagem dos Produtos Ordenados Pelo Campo: 2 -----")
    for linha in produtos:
        print(tuple(linha))
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print()
```

Alguma luz de como resolver?

Comment: Mas a ordenação é a mesma nos 3 campos, por que você vai ter três funções que fazem a mesma coisa? Não é mais fácil implementar o parâmetro `key` na sua função e usar a mesma pra ordenar os 3 campos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar seu próprio parâmetro `key` que vai pegar o valor para fazer a comparação entre valores. Aí ao invés de fazer:

```
if a > b:
```

Você faz:

```
if key(a) > key(b)
```

---

#### Exemplo

```
def bubble_sort(lista, key):
    while True:
        trocou = False

        for i in range(len(lista) - 1):
            if key(lista[i]) > key(lista[i+1]):
                lista[i], lista[i+1] = lista[i+1], lista[i]
                trocou = True

        if not trocou:
            break

    return lista
```

<sup>Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-373522-6333)</sup>

---

Agora basta selecionar qual é o item que vai ser usado na comparação.

```
print('=== ordenado por nome')
for x in bubble_sort(dados, lambda x: x[0]):
    print(x)


print('=== ordenado por qtde')
for x in bubble_sort(dados, lambda x: x[1]):
    print(x)


print('=== ordenado por preco')
for x in bubble_sort(dados, lambda x: x[2]):
    print(x)
```

A saída seria:

```
=== ordenado por nome
('abacaxi', 100, 3.99)
('arroz', 5, 4.99)
('beringela', 10, 1.99)
('peixe', 2, 9.99)

=== ordenado por qtde
('peixe', 2, 9.99)
('arroz', 5, 4.99)
('beringela', 10, 1.99)
('abacaxi', 100, 3.99)

=== ordenado por preco
('beringela', 10, 1.99)
('abacaxi', 100, 3.99)
('arroz', 5, 4.99)
('peixe', 2, 9.99)
```

---

#### Explicação

A única modificação feita no método `bubble_sort` "normal" é que a comparação não é feita diretamente com os valores da lista e sim com uma "versão modificada" por uma função. Basta que a função retorne os valores que você quer comparar para a ordenação.

No seu caso, você quer comparar o 3º elemento da tupla, que é o item a ser ordenado. Então basta você fazer uma função que receba esta tupla e retorne apenas o 3º elemento.

```
def pega_terceiro(minha_tupla):
    return minha_tupla[2]

bubble_sort(dados, pega_terceiro)
```

Dessa maneira a comparação entre os elementos da lista vai ser feita usando apenas o 3º elemento de cada tupla, como você deseja.

No python você também pode criar uma função [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), que é uma função anônima simples e curta.

A seguinte função tem o mesmo efeito que a função `pega_terceiro` do código acima:

```
lambda minha_tupla: minha_tupla[2]
```

Para fins de conhecimento, o python possui um módulo chamado `operator`. Este módulo contém a função [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), cujo objetivo e retornar outra função que acessa o item N de um iterável.

Isso significa que as 3 funções abaixo desempenham o mesmo papel no nosso método de ordenação:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def pega_terceiro(minha_tupla):
    return minha_tupla[2]

pega_terceiro = lambda minha_tupla: minha_tupla[2]

pega_terceiro = itemgetter(2)
```

Comment: A dica que você deu funcionou, mas você consegue me explicar melhor sobre essa linha ```if key(lista[i]) > key(lista[i+1]):``` ou me indicar algum material que possa me ajudar? Não entendi muito bem como o ```lambda x: x[1]``` por exemplo entraria no lugar da key.

Comment: Eu vou criar a sessão para explicar melhor. Só não posso agora, hoje de tarde complemento a questão

Comment: @CaioTracera complementei a resposta. Agora deve estar mais claro o que foi feito. Linkei a documentação nos pontos importantes pra ter referências.